# Can't install YStockData.jl in Julia 1.4

Tags: julia, finance

I am trying to add the Yahoo Finance package YStockData.jl to Julia 1.4 without success. The package's page at JuliaObserver says

This package is not yet in the official package repository. Therefore, to install, use the following invocation `Pkg.clone("https://github.com/Algocircle/YStockData.jl")`

However, this fails with the following:

`UndefVarError: clone not defined`

(Is Pkg.clone no longer working?) So I tried

`Pkg.add(PackageSpec(url="https://github.com/Algocircle/YStockData.jl"))`

which caused this response:

Updating git-repo `https://github.com/Algocircle/YStockData.jl`

could not find project file in package at `https://github.com/Algocircle/YStockData.jl`

So now what? This project was last updated three years ago.

I found a similar result trying to install Quandl which can also download financial data--missing project file.

How do others download financial data with Julia?

Comment: The package manager has been through some *major* updates since this package was last active. The problem you are encountering is that this package does not have a `project.toml` file. Instead, it still has the old `REQUIRE` file. However, Julia itself has also undergone some major changes. This is likely only the first of many updates that need to be implemented in order to get this package working on v1.4. If you are really keen, your best bet is to just manually download the package and start working on updating it piece by piece.

Comment: Actually, on second thought, the Yahoo API has also *massively* changed in the meantime. Even if you updated this package to be compatible with Julia v1.4, you would find that it still doesn't work, because Yahoo are far more stringent on what they give out via their API these days. Long gone are the days where you could just pull thousands of daily observations across thousands of securities.

Comment: If you really want to download large quantities of data these days from Yahoo, you'll need to get your hands dirty with web-scraping tools. Personally, if you're just after daily data, you are significantly better off buying it from a reliable vendor who handles all the nasty corporate action stuff for you.

Comment: I have long wanted to download historical financial data but am only now getting serious about it. Besides Julia-related problems I might have worse problems with finding a source. Yes, I want to download years of historical data to run experiments. I was hoping for a pre-built solution. I think Mathematica can do it. In fact I checked WolframAlpha.com and they cite Quandl for their data source. Of course, the Julia Quandl package is also obsolete, missing a project file. Is that something that I could replace in the repo? I don't know anything about project files but Quandl looks interesting.

Comment: I guess it depends what you're after. If you just want a one-time download of historical data, you don't need a package at all. Just do a one-time download from your vendor of choice (Quandl are probably fine) in some easily readable file format. Then just use whatever language you want. If you want a data-feed, or API based interaction, then Julia isn't the ideal language (yet) unless you want to do a lot of work yourself. If you like the Julia language (I do!) then a better option might be to get your data using a Python library, then use Julia with PyCall.

Answer (score 1):

One new option to do this in Julia is to use Alpha Vantage through the [AlphaVantage.jl](https://github.com/ellisvalentiner/AlphaVantage.jl) package.